# xunit "could not load type" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

I inherited a project and the tests ran fine. Today, I created a new class, and xunit errors out when I try to use this class in a test.

Both the test project and the app are targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1.

I do clean and rebuild on the both the solution and the test project, but I still get the error.

**error:**

Could not load type 'MyNewClass' from assembly 'MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

**project.json:**

```
"buildOptions": {
  "warningsAsErrors": true
},
"testRunner": "xunit",
"dependencies": {
  "xunit": "2.2.0-beta4-build3404",
  "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
  "MyApp": "1.0.0-*",
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "1.0.0",
  "NSubstitute": "1.9.2"
},

"frameworks": {
    "net461": {
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: NameSpace missing for MyNewClass. check where this class is declared. and put it in the required NameSpace

Comment: try and let me know whether it has fixed your prob?

Comment: it's in the same namespace as other classes that are used in the test project. don't think that's it, but thanks for trying @viveknuna

Comment: just rename dll and then try

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes for whatever reason `.NET Core` dependencies restore won't work as expected. I've just tried your `project.json` on my machine and it was complaining about `xunit` version, however after several `project.json` edits it was able to restore all the dependencies, and run tests successfully.

In such situations following might help:

1. Try `dotnet restore` and/or `dotnet build` commands in the folder where your `project.json` file is.
2. Delete `project.json.lock` file and try step #1.
3. Use `dotnet test` to run unit tests.

I find these commands to run `.NET Core` projects more stable and provide better error output for troubleshooting than Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

So, my problem was that MyApp.dll was not getting updated/re-created, even after I did a clean and rebuild. I had to physically delete the files (including MyApp.dll) in MyApp\test\MyApp.Tests\bin\Debug\net461\win7-x86

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too and could solve it recreating the project.

Sometimes, things simply stops working correctly, as pointed in the others answers, and the best is just start over, restart the program, recreate the project, reboot the machine...

This is Visual Studio, sigh... :)