# Unit Test Failing with Moq and xUnit - InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq, xunit

Im setting up a simple integration test using Moq and Xunit as per this article :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

When I run the test I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Can't load type x.IntegrationTests.Startup in 'x.IntegrationTests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

**HomeControllerTests.cs**

```
public class HomeControllerTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Test()
        {
            Assert.True(true);
        }
    }
```

**csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.15.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.3.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\x\x.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="xunit.runner.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: How did you run the test?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski using xunit.runner.visualstudio

Comment: Do you have a class `Startup` under namespace `x.IntegrationTests`? in your test project?

Comment: @user1672994 No i do not, following the documentation, there is no mention that this would be needed

Comment: @Vince - no, it's not needed. But in your exception message states that unable to load type `x.IntegrationTests.Startup`

Comment: @user1672994 that is why it is puzzling, because nowhere do i mention this class

Comment: What happens if you download the sample (mentioned in link posted in your question) and run it then do you get the same error? Either it's possible that one of the referenced package has some issue or something wrong with the your setup. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293669/xunit-could-not-load-type-error)

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace? Can't really understand what's going on or what that 'x' represents.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm encountering the same issue.

Comment: @Gavin, sadly not

Comment: @Vince I got it working in the end by moving my Moq code into test fixtures IClassFixture. I added the Moq version of a service to the ServiceCollection. I'll post a loose answer that might work for you. Can't remember the exact details now but hopefully might lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found moving my Moq'd services to test fixtures worked. Hopefully the following loose example may give you something to work with...

Fixture:

```
public class MyTestServicesFixture
{
    public MyTestServicesFixture()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        ...

        var mockDataService = new Mock<IPhotoCollectionDataService>();
        mockDataService.Setup(s => s.GetPhotoAsync((int)TestPhotoIds.TestJpegImage))
            .ReturnsAsync(() =>
            {
                return BuildTestPhotoEntity(TestPhotoIds.TestJpegImage, "example.jpg");
            }
            );
        mockDataService.Setup(s => s.GetPhotoAsync((int)TestPhotoIds.TestHeifStillImage))
            .ReturnsAsync(() => 
            {
                return BuildTestPhotoEntity(TestPhotoIds.TestHeifStillImage, "example.heic");
            }
            );
        services.AddScoped(sp => mockDataService.Object);

        ...

        ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    public ServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }

    private Photo BuildTestPhotoEntity(TestPhotoIds testPhotoId, string fileName)
    {
        return new Photo
        {
            Id = (int)testPhotoId,
            PhotoCollectionId = TestSettings.TEST_PHOTO_COLLECTION_ID,
            OriginalFileName = fileName,
            UploadFileName = fileName,
            Description = $"Test description for {fileName}"
        };
    }
}
```

Tests using fixture:

```
public class PhotoCollectionServiceTests : IClassFixture<MyTestServicesFixture>
{
    protected readonly IPhotoCollectionDataService _photoCollectionDataService;

    public PhotoCollectionServiceTests(MyTestServicesFixture testsFixture)
    {
        var services = testsFixture.ServiceProvider;
        _photoCollectionDataService = services.GetRequiredService<IPhotoCollectionDataService>();
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData(TestPhotoIds.TestJpegImage)]
    [InlineData(TestPhotoIds.TestHeifStillImage)]
    public async Task ProcessPhotoUploadTest(TestPhotoIds testPhotoId)
    {
        // Arrange

        ...

        // Act

        var result = _photoCollectionDataService.DoSomething(testPhotoId);

        // Assert

        ...

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, i have given up on this!